# error while importing Tkinter in python

Tags: python

I get the following error while importing Tkinter:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 11 2011, 11:34:27) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
>>>
```

What shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

Probably just install Tkinter - maybe `apt-get install python-tk` will do it if you have a Debian based distribution. Might be `python3-tk` or something else for other distributions.

Answer (score -1):

You can try doing instead

```
from tkinter import *
```

I dont know why but this seems to work foor me it just means from tkinter import all.
another thing they changed it in python 3.5 to a lower case t. just for future knowledge.